# jQuery slideDown not working on element with dynamically assigned id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

EDIT: I cleaned up the code a bit and narrowed down the problem.

So I'm working on a Wordpress site, and I'm trying to incorporate drop-downs into my menu on mobile, which means I have to use jQuery to assign classes and id's to my already existing elements. I have this code that already works on premade HTML, but fails on dynamically created id's.

Here is the code:

```
...
var menuCount = 0;
var contentCount = 0;
//find the mobile menu items
var submenus = $('[title="submenu"]');
if (submenus.length && submenus.parent('.fusion-mobile-nav-item')) {
    console.log(submenus);
    submenus.addClass('dropdown-title').append('<i id="dropdown-angle" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    submenus.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "#m" + menuCount++);
    })
    var content = submenus.parent().find('ul.sub-menu');
    content.addClass('dropdown-content');
    content.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", "m" + contentCount++);
    })
}

$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-title', function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(e.target).is('.d-active') || $(e.target).parent('.dropdown-title').is('.d-active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('d-active');
        $(currentAttrValue).slideUp(300).removeClass('d-open');
    } else {
        $('.dropdown-title').removeClass('d-active');
        $('.dropdown-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('d-open');
        $(this).addClass('d-active');
        console.log($(currentAttrValue));

        //THIS LINE FAILS
        $(currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('d-open');
    }

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I've registered the elements with the class `dropdown-title` using `$(document).on(...)` but I can't figure out what I need to do to register the elements with the custom ID's. I've tried putting the event callback inside the `.each` functions, I've tried making custom events to trigger, but none of them will get the 2nd to last line of code to trigger. There's no errors in the console, and when I console log the selector I get this:

[ul#m0.sub-menu.dropdown-content, context: document, selector: "#m0"]
0
:
ul#m0.sub-menu.dropdown-content
context
:
document
length
:
1
selector
:
"#m0"
**proto**
:
Object[0]

So jQuery knows the element is there, I just can't figure out how to register it...or maybe it's something I'm not thinking of, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your elements dynamically, you should be assigning the `.on` 'click' after creating those elements. Just declare the 'on click' callback code you posted after adding the ids and classes instead of when the page loads, so it gets attached to the elements with `.dropdown-title` class.

Check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zayouxc/

EDIT: Your edited JS code works... There also might be some problem with your HTML or CSS, are you hiding your submenus? Make sure you are not making them transparent.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm not sure I understand. I don't want the content to be click able, just the titles.

Comment: Yes, I hide them by adding 'display: none' to the dropdown-content's css and then the jQuery animation should do the rest. What's confusing me is why it won't even add the d-open class to the elements either, even when I take out the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a function for a attribute, instead of the element. You probably want `$(this).slideDown(300).addClass('d-active');` (also then you don't need `$(this).addClass('d-active');` before)

Comment: No, I need to select the element WITH that Id. $(this) refers to the drop down title, not the drop down content.

Comment: The href value is something like #m0 so that automatically gets converted to an Id when selected in jQuery

Comment: You can do so: `$(this).find('#' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(...)` (not sure for sharp)

Comment: that didn't work either. The element exists, it's just not registered with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `submenus.each` loop add your callback listener.

As you are adding the class `dropdown-title` dynamically, it was not available at dom loading time, that is why event listener was not attached with those elemnts.

```
var menuCount = 0;
var contentCount = 0;
//find the mobile menu items
var submenus = $('[title="submenu"]');
if (submenus.length && submenus.parent('.fusion-mobile-nav-item')) {
    console.log(submenus);
    submenus.addClass('dropdown-title').append('<i id="dropdown-angle" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    submenus.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "#m" + menuCount++);

        // add callback here
        $(this).click( function(e) {
            var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

            if ($(e.target).is('.d-active') || $(e.target).parent('.dropdown-title').is('.d-active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('d-active');
                $(currentAttrValue).slideUp(300).removeClass('d-open');
            } else {
                $('.dropdown-title').removeClass('d-active');
                $('.dropdown-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('d-open');
                $(this).addClass('d-active');
                console.log($(currentAttrValue));

                $(currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('d-active');
            }

            e.preventDefault();

        });


    })
    var content = submenus.parent().find('ul.sub-menu');
    content.addClass('dropdown-content');
    content.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", "m" + contentCount++);
    })
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't getting the `dropdown-title` event to fire, it fires just fine on every click. The problem is within that event, getting jQuery to register the ID's that I assigned my `dropdown-content` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem is that jQuery is adding to both the mobile menu and the desktop menu, where the desktop menu is being loaded first when I search for that ID that's the one that jQuery finds. So it turns out I was completely wrong about my suspicions.